# How can a simple date variable hurt my runperformance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that runs in 10 seconds when I hardcode a date.

But if i create a simple variable that contains the date, my performance takes hours.

This happens inside a stored procedure or even just in new query.

The execution plan doesn't show anything notable.  I have a bunch of needed indexes for these joins.

Any ideas on why there would be such a difference?

```
declare @datetouse datetime = '2022-03-05'
SELECT   i.*, isnull(fm.guidsolo, sm.guidsolo) as guidsoloExists
        FROM IngestItems i
    left join Ingested_Main nm on i.guidsolo = nm.guidsolo
    left join Files_Main fm on nm.CollectionName = fm.CollectionName
                            and nm.CollectionYear = fm.CollectionYear
                            and nm.CollectionMonth = fm.CollectionMonth
                            and nm.CollectionDay = fm.Collectionday
    left join FilesStaged_Main sm on nm.CollectionName = sm.CollectionName
                            and nm.CollectionYear = sm.CollectionYear
                            and nm.CollectionMonth = sm.CollectionMonth
                            and nm.CollectionDay = sm.CollectionDay
    Where i.DateRetreived > @datetouse   ---- with this line takes forever
    --WHERE i.DateRetrieved > '2022-03-05'   ------ with this line it takes 10 seconds
    ORDER BY i.description;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See generally [Query Processing Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15).

With the variable SQL Server must select a query plan that will work acceptably for any value of the variable.

If it were a stored procedure parameter, or a client API parameter then SQL Server would select a query plan that will work acceptably for any value, but could pick a plan that favors the first value used (aka Parameter Sniffing).

If you hard-code the value, SQL Server can pick a plan that is optimal for that one value since that query plan won’t be reused for any other value.

Adding OPTION RECOMPILE or OPTION OPTIMIZE FOR [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15) you can change this behavior.

eg

```
    OPTION( RECOMPILE )
```

or

```
    OPTION( OPTIMIZE FOR (  @datetouse =  '2022-03-05' ) )
```

But if you use OPTIMIZE FOR may need to update the query every day or week to keep it close to the current date.

Comment: Wow.  After over a decade of using SQL, I never realized this was an option.  I have a lot of reading to do.

How would i specify the OPTION OPTIMIZE FOR with a hardcoded date?s  Looking through the referenced links nothing jumped out at me.